# How do I go about streaming an audio file in Django?

Tags: python, django, streaming

I am trying to get Django to stream audio files over the internet from a given link. How can I accomplish that?

Comment: do you want to write a media server using django? or have django serve html/js that can stream media?

Answer (score 0):

You should'n serve static content using Django, use a server like Nginx or Apache instead.

Or also some cloud service like [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/).

Comment: Is there a tutorial or step-by-step breakdown of how to do this with Amazon S3? I'm having this same issue.